# How to find the expected value of a function.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An appliance dealer sells three different models of freezers having 13.5, 15.9, and 19.1 cubic feet of storage space. Let $X$ be the amount of storage space purchased by the next customer to buy a freezer. Suppose that $X$ has pmf $p(13.5)=0.2$, $p(15.9)=0.5$, and $p(19.1)=0.3$.

Suppose that although the rated capacity of a freezer is $X$, the actual capacity is $h(X)=X-0.1X^2$. What is the expected actual capacity of the freezer purchased by the next customer?

I know that I am supposed to find $E(X-0.01X^2)$, I found a formula in the textbook that I was using saying that $E[h(x)]=\sum_D h(x)p(x)$ where $D$ is the set of possible values of the random variable $X$. I wasn't sure if this was the formula used to solve the problem. In a solution I found online, the answer was $E(X-0.01X^2)=E(X)-0.01E(X^2)$.

Could someone explain how they got that answer? I thought I was supposed to use the formula from the textbook. I couldn't find any properties of expected values that allow you to split it up like that in my book.

Comment: Doesn't your freezers have negative capacity? $X - 0.1X^2$ is less than zero for $X = 13.5$, $15.9$ and $19.1$.

Comment: Oops, It should be $-0.01$, I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be the storage spaces of freezers. Then you can simply count actual capacity of each freezer.
$$h(X_1) = 13.5 - 0.01 * 13.5^2 = 11.6775$$
$$h(X_2) = 15.9 - 0.01 * 15.9^2 = 13.3719$$
$$h(X_3) = 19.1 - 0.01 * 19.1^2 = 15.4519$$
Then e.v. of actual capacity is obviously
$$E(X) = p_1h(X_1) + p_2h(X_2) + p_3h(X_3)$$
Just put the values in the last formula and count $E(X)$.

Comment: So the formula I mentioned that was in my book could be used for this problem? I was thinking to use the formula but didn't know how to plug in the values.

Comment: Sure. This formula doesn't contain anything new. It says that if you have a random variable $X$ and some function $h(X)$ taking this variable as an argument, then $h(X)$ can be also considered as a random variable, therefore if $E(X) = \Sigma xp(x)$, then, substituiting $X$ with $h(X)$, $E(h(X)) = \Sigma h(x)p(h(x))$, in this case $p(h(x)) = p(x)$, so $E(h(X)) = \Sigma h(x)p(x)$

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty proof that we can say: $\mathsf E[h(X)] = \sum_{\cal D} h(x)\mathsf {P_X}(x)$

For a discrete random variable X measurable over support $\mathcal D$ and a monovariate function $h:\mathcal D\to \mathcal H$, we have:

$\begin{align}
\mathsf E_{h(X)}[h(X)] & =
\sum_{y\in\mathcal H} y \mathsf P(h(X)= y) & \text{by definition of expectation}
\\[1ex] & =\sum_{y\in\mathcal H} y \sum_{x\in\mathcal D} \mathsf P(X=x, h(X)= y)
& \text{by law of total probability} 
\\[1ex] & = \sum_{y\in\mathcal H} y \sum_{x\in\mathcal D\mid h(x)=y} \mathsf P(X=x)
& \ni \mathsf P(X=x, h(X)= y) \equiv \begin{cases} \mathsf P(X=x) & h(x)=y \\ 0 & h(x)\neq y\end{cases} 
\\[1ex] & = \sum_{x\in\mathcal D} \mathsf P(X=x)\sum_{y\in\mathcal H\mid y=h(x)} y 
& \text{exchange order of summation}
\\[1ex] & = \sum_{x\in\mathcal D} h(x) \mathsf P(X=x)
\\[3ex]
\therefore \mathsf E_{h(X)}[h(X)] &= \mathsf E_{X}[h(X)]
\\[2ex] & = \sum_{x\in\mathcal D} h(x)\mathsf {P_X}(x)
\end{align}$

This can be extended similarly for continuous random variables, by using integration (or sigma algebra) as appropriate.

---

For the other half of your question $\mathsf E[aX+bX^2]= a\mathsf E[X]+b\mathsf E[X^2]$ is a property called: the Linearity of Expectation.  It follows from the result shown above.

$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[aX + bX^2] & = \sum_\mathcal D (ax+bx^2)\mathsf P_X(x) & \text{as above}
\\[1ex] & = a \sum_\mathcal D (x\mathsf P_X(x)) + b \sum_\mathcal D (x^2\mathsf P_X(x))  
\\[1ex] & = a\mathsf E[X] + b\mathsf E[X^2] & \text{as above}
\end{align}$

---

So you can use whichever method is easier to crunch from the dataset.  Find $\mathsf E[X]$ and $\mathsf E[X^2]$, and then calculate $\mathsf E[X]-0.01\mathsf E[X^2]$, or just find $\mathsf E[X-0.01X^2]$.  They give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

$E(aX+bY)=\sum (aX+bY) P(x=X) = \sum (aX)P(x=X) + \sum (bY)P(x=X)=a\sum (X)P(x=X) + b\sum (Y)P(x=X)=aE(X)+bE(Y)$